# C# REST Client Example?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, client

Ive been looking everywhere, and nothing seems to work.

Im trying to connect to my REST (WCF) Service. It works fine in firefox using the following:

```
http://localhost:1337/WCF.IService.svc/rest/Services?CostCentreNo=1&Filter=1
```

Where `rest` is the endpoint address;
`Services?CostCentreNo=1&Filter=1` is the template with params

Below is the Server contract point.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Services?CostCentreNo={CostCentreNo}&Filter={Filter}")]
    List<Services> GetServices(Int32 CostCentreNo, Int32 Filter);
```

**Can I get a working example of connecting to this please from c#..**

Comment: Create a client app and add a Service Reference?

Comment: Have you tried this [Consuming WCF Services] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic6)

Comment: Both only work for SOAP as far as im aware (I just checked again). Where as I want to test REST works.

Comment: Do either of the answers provided answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for JSON:

```
String resonse = String.Empty;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = client.Get("your_uri"))
{
   response = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

This code requires the `Microsoft.Http` and `Microsoft.Http.Extensions` dlls from the WCF Rest Toolkit - http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own proxy by extending `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IYourServiceContract>`.  Each of your methods on the REST service is exposed through the `Channel` property, so you can then wrap these.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ping")]
    string Ping();
}

public class ProxyClient : ClientBase<IMyServiceContract>, IMyServiceContract
{
    #region Implementation of IMyServiceContract

    public string Ping()
    {
        return Channel.Ping();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Test
{
    // This assumes you have setup a client endpoint in your .config file
    // that is bound to IMyServiceContract.
    var client = new Client();

    System.Console("Ping replied: " + client.Ping());
}
```

Unfortunately, this is aimed at WCF consumption and doesn't work perfectly with REST, i.e. it doesn't expose the HTTP headers, which are necessary for a RESTful implementation.

Comment: I was missing the [WebGet....] attribute.  Didn't realize this was needed on client.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic/dynamic solution with sample source see http://www.nikhilk.net/CSharp-Dynamic-Programming-REST-Services.aspx